# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js

Tags: phantom, react

i'm using react, vite, @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets to connect phantom wallet but i stuck with this error:

[image]

Help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a compatibility issue.

If you are using Webpack 5 then you can try modifying your `config-overrides.js` file to include the following override:

```
...

webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
  ...
  process: false,
  ...
};

...
```